# How to stop gunicorn_django in virtualenv?

Tags: django, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am trying out gunicorn, and I installed it inside a virtualenv with a django site. I got gunicorn running with this command:

```
gunicorn_django -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Which is all well and good. I haven't setup a bash script or hooked it to upstart (I am on Ubuntu) yet, because I am testing it out.

Meantime, my connection to the server was broken, and thus I lost the console, and I can no longer do CTRL + C to stop the server after reconnecting.

How do I stop gunicorn_django, when it is already running?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The general solution to problems like this is to do `ps ax|grep gunicorn` to look for the relevant process, then do `kill xxxx` where xxxx is the number in the first column.

Answer (score 20):

Just found this also - `pkill` - which will kill all processes matching the search text:

```
$ pkill gunicorn
```

No idea how well supported it is, but can confirm that it works on Ubuntu 12.04

(from http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/kill-linux-processes-easier-with-pkill/)

Answer (score 15):

A faster way:

```
> kill -9 `ps aux | grep gunicorn | awk '{print $2}'`
```

updated code

Comment: To improve this a little bit:   **kill -9 \`ps aux |grep gunicorn |grep your_app_name | awk '{ print $2 }'\`**

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that has just been fixed [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/356).